# How can I deselect an entire group based on the value of one member of the group?

Tags: crystal-reports

We have customers that order product on an annual basis.  I have a report that needs to show only customers and related orders that have NOT placed an order in the current year.  I filter all orders down to the current year and the year prior.

Right now, if a customer has orders for last year, I want them to show on the report, but once the customer places an order for the current year, I want both the current year order and the prior year orders to drop off the report.

Our salespeople use this report to manage the customers that need to be contacted in the current year.  Once the report is empty, they are done for the year.

I know how to suppress the rows based on the value of a single member of the group, but suppressing them does not remove them from the summary calculations, so I need them to either disappear, or I need to be able to change all values to zero for that customer once they place a new order.

Thank You.

I created a running total field to trap the current year.

If Year(@Date)=2019 then 0 else Qty

When I put the formula into a qty formula, I get the "Summary has been specified for a non-recurring field"